# How to create Page Objects classes for Rspec Features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have been trying, unsuccessfully, refactor some rspec features using Page Objects, but I'm having a hard time with it.

I'm not a experienced RoR developers. Probably this is a basic error.

I have a spec feature like this:

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
feature 'Acessing the dashboard' do

    scenario 'User see the dashboard after login' do
      sign_in 'teste','123' 
      expect(page).to have_css 'h1', text: 'Dashboard'
    end

    def sign_in(login, password)
      visit '/'
      fill_in 'login', :with => login
      fill_in 'password', :with => password
      click_button 'Autenticar'
    end 
end
```

But, I would like to share my sign_in method with another features through a Login Page Object like this:

```
class LoginPage
   include Capybara::DSL

   def sign_in(login, password)
      visit '/'
      fill_in 'login', :with => login
      fill_in 'password', :with => password
      click_button 'Authenticate'
   end
end
```

So, I changed my feature:

```
feature 'Acessing the dashboard' do

    let(:login_page) { LoginPage.new }

    scenario 'User see the dashboard after login' do
      login_page.sign_in 'teste','123'
      expect(page).to have_css 'h1', text: 'Dashboard'
    end

end
```

But I receive the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: let(:login_page) { LoginPage.new }
 NameError: uninitialized constant LoginPage
```

I really don't know what to do. 
I created the LoginPage class in /spec/support/LoginPage.rb.  Is it correct? Should I put this class in other path?

Somebody can help me to deal with it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you requiring this Class in your test? or Your code have something like this is the `spec_helper.rb`? : `Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }`

Comment: Hello rockskull.. No, I didn't have the code block in my spec_helper. Now it's fixed. Thanks a lot...

Comment: Gald to help. I've put that in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to require your support folder files in you `spec_helper.rb` file

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
```